Cannot loop over files in /run/secrets in Docker
Is looping over files in /run/secrets (coming from docker compose secrets: clause) forbidden in Docker; or perhaps, sh?
I am trying to do this in a script called by ENTRYPOINT:
#!/bin/sh
…
cd /run/secrets/users
ls -l # A list of files, proving that the secrets are present, is output.

for username in *; do
      echo "username is «$username»" # But $username is empty here.
done

The output of ls -l and echo is:
(container name)  | total 8
(container name)  | -rw-r--r--    1 root     root             9 May 17 17:08 file1
(container name)  | -rw-r--r--    1 root     root             5 May 17 17:08 file2
(container name)  | username is «»


The docker image is built on alpine.
Docker version 26.1.3, build b72abbb.
Docker Compose version v2.27.0.

I was expecting that the variable username would contain the name of each file in /run/secrets/users.
UPDATE:
The failing script, which was copied from heredoc, had $username expanded by the Docker build process, where, of course, it was not set. I had either to double the dollar sign, or invoke the heredoc using this syntax (unless there were variables that really had to be expanded during build):
COPY --chmod=+x <<-'START' /bin/start.sh
…
# "$username" will now work.
…
START

Note the single quotes around 'START'.

Thank you, but resolved; see the updated question.

Please see [mcve]. This question is missing a complete example to reproduce the error.

Suppose that your project directory looks like this:
├── Dockerfile
├── entrypoint.sh
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3

The entrypoint script remains the same as in the question:
#!/bin/sh

cd /run/secrets/users
ls -l

for username in *; do
      echo "username is «$username»"
done

You did not provide a Dockerfile but this will do the job:
FROM alpine:latest

COPY file* /run/secrets/users/

COPY entrypoint.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]

Run with something like this:
docker build -t secrets . && docker run -it secrets

That will copy the files onto the image.

You could make this more flexible though by sharing a volume with the running container. Change the project structure:
├── Dockerfile
├── entrypoint.sh
└── users
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── file3

Update Dockerfile:
FROM alpine:latest

COPY entrypoint.sh .

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "entrypoint.sh"]

Now mount the users folder as a volume.
docker build -t secrets .
docker run -it -v ./users/:/run/secrets/users/ secrets

This is a more flexible approach since you won't need to rebuild the image when you add or alter the user files.

Thank you, but I should have made clear that /run/secrets/users directory was filled by secrets: clause in docker-compose.yml.

Thank you. Resolved, it was a misused heredoc.
